# Do measurable "sparsenings" of the Interval exist?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm a little unsure about terminology, but I am looking at a subset $I_a$ of $[0,1]$ that satisfies the following properties ($0≤a≤1$):

1. $I_a$ is measurable and has measure $a$.
2. $I_a$ is dense in $[0,1]$.
3. For any sub-interval $[b,c]\subset[0,1]$ the measure of $I_a \cap [b,c]$ is $a\, (c-b)$.

The difficult condition is 3. Basically the idea is to have a set where $1-a$ of the measure is thrown away in a homogenous way, sparsening the interval so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all 1) and 2) are consequences of 3), and secondly a set like $I_a$ **doesn't exists**.

Suppose $I_a$ exists and is measurable for an $0<a<1$. By the properties of lebesgue measure for every $\varepsilon>0$ there existe a (countable) covering of $I_a$ by open intervals : $ I_a\subset \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty P_i $ such that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda( P_i)<\lambda(I_a)+\varepsilon$. Now, by the properties of $I_a$, we must have $\lambda(I_a\cap P_i)=a\lambda(P_i)$ for all $i$, and thus

$$\lambda(I_a\cap \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty P_i)=\lambda(\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty (P_i\cap I_a))\leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda(P_i \cap I_a)\leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty a\lambda(P_i)\leq a(\lambda(I_a)+\varepsilon)\leq a(a+\varepsilon)$$

But $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty P_i$ is a covering of $I_a$ so $\lambda(I_a\cap \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty P_i)=\lambda(I_a)=a$, combining these we have $a\leq a^2+a\varepsilon $, but since $0<a<1$ for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small we obtain $a^2+a\varepsilon<a$, contradiction.

However sets like $I_0$ and $I_1$ can be found easily.

So where is the error in Jonas response ? Well i'm pretty convinced that his set has either null or full measure.

Comment: Quite right, after thinking more I have to conclude that the set has full measure for $a\ge1/2$ and zero measure otherwise. Just upvoted your answer.